# bash: for loop to retrieve all files in directory only returns one

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have made a directory with lots of files with:

```
samplefile_111222015_reporting_{1..13}
```

I am trying to create a vi script where when I enter the directory as an argument to the command e.g.

```
sh myScript $HOME/theDir/*
```

then it copies all the files in that directory to a new one I made. Although right now, I'm having problems with the for loop alone.
This is what I have in my script:

```
for f in $1;
do
echo "$f"
done
```

but when i enter sh myScript $HOME/theDir, I get back the name of the first file only (samplefile_111222015_reporting_1). why the first file? Is this not a for loop>

Comment: Your example of use of your script `sh myScript $HOME/theDir/*` is not what you claim: use `sh myScript $HOME/theDir` instead. Then, using what CaptainObv suggests should make it.

Comment: Before your shell runs your script with `sh` it replaces `$HOME/theDir/*` by all possible valid filenames and then `$1` contains only the first filename. `$2` contains second filename ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because each file is passed as a separate argument and you're only looping over `$1`, which is the first argument.

Instead, you most likely want to loop over `"$@"`, which is every argument starting from `$1`.

The man page for bash, under the `Special Parameters` section, details the special parameters available in more detail.

Comment: Ahh, I thought $1 referred to the first argument in sh myScript

Comment: @CaptainObv it does, but that's only the first file. Since you're using wildcard expansion to list all the files, each file is passed as a separate argument (e.g. `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4` if there's four files) which is why you want `$@` (all arguments)

Comment: @CaptainObv: use `for f in "$@"`.

Comment: Your script does't receive the string `$HOME/theDir/*` as its first argument (unless the calling shell doesn't find any matches). The shell expands it to a list of matching files, and each of *those* is passed as the set of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Because of the wild card expansion, all the files in the directory are  
# already made available to the script  through arguments  
# So do the following to get all the file listing  
for f ; do echo $f; done
```